# Searching a integer type database field through java

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to search the database by giving a voucher number as search criteria but vouch number is integer so i cannot do this with the following code, please suggest some other code for this.

```
  try{
            String sql = "select item_type as 'Item Type', md_by as 'Made By', model as       'Model', selling_price as 'Selling Price', purchase_price as 'Purchase Price', purchase_date as 'Purchase Date', vouch_no as 'Voucher No.', vouch_date as 'Voucher Date', record_no as 'Record No.' from purchase" where vouch_no = ?;
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1 , txt_vouchno_p.getText());
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            Table_p.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));


        }   
        catch(SQLException ex){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ex);

        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the value of `txt_vouchno_p.getText()` into an `int` using [`Integer#parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) and pass it to your `PreparedStatement` accordingly:

```
ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(txt_vouchno_p.getText()));
```

---

Looks like a typo in your current code, but for large literal `String`s, do not be afraid o split it in several lines, the compiler is smart enough to convert it into a single large `String` for you. So, this line:

```
String sql = "select item_type as 'Item Type', md_by as 'Made By', model as       'Model', selling_price as 'Selling Price', purchase_price as 'Purchase Price', purchase_date as 'Purchase Date', vouch_no as 'Voucher No.', vouch_date as 'Voucher Date', record_no as 'Record No.' from purchase" where vouch_no = ?;
```

Should be rewritten to:

```
String sql = "select item_type as 'Item Type'"
    + ", md_by as 'Made By'"
    + ", model as 'Model'"
    + ", selling_price as 'Selling Price'"
    + ", purchase_price as 'Purchase Price'"
    + ", purchase_date as 'Purchase Date'"
    + ", vouch_no as 'Voucher No.'"
    + ", vouch_date as 'Voucher Date'"
    + ", record_no as 'Record No.'"
    + " from purchase"
    + " where vouch_no = ?";
```

Comment: I tried to parse but still i got error. I tried to parse as float too but didn't work.

Comment: @user3248599 please edit your question and post the stacktrace of your error. Also, make sure that the content of `txt_vouchno_p.getText()` can be converted into an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple error in your code ("where vouch_no..." is not inside the string sql), it should be:

```
 String sql = "select item_type as 'Item Type', md_by as 'Made By', model as       'Model', selling_price as 'Selling Price', purchase_price as 'Purchase Price', purchase_date as 'Purchase Date', vouch_no as 'Voucher No.', vouch_date as 'Voucher Date', record_no as 'Record No.' from purchase where vouch_no = ?";
```

You can set the parameter like this:

```
ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1 , Integer.parseInt(txt_vouchno_p.getText()));
```